# No se mantiene logueo en Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identity

Tengo un proyecto MVC, donde uso Identity y Owin para la autenticacion y autorizacion de usuarios. Mi problema esta en que no esta manteniendo la autenticacion de estos. Por ejemplo, en mi caso un usuario puede tener dos roles "Cliente" o "Administrador", si es el segundo puede realizar una operacion por ejemplo de registrar una noticia. Lo que me esta pasando es que al crear la noticia esta lo hace bien, pero una vez que uso un RedirectToAction o un script con JS para usar un boton que tenga un Url.Action, tengo que volver a loguearme. No se bien que codigo dejar porque pasar todos las acciones de Identity seria imposible, asi que les dejo lo que estoy probando.
Accion de registrar cliente:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrador")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Nombre = model.Nombre, Apellido = model.Apellido, Direccion = model.Direccion, Estado = true, PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber};
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                ViewBag.Usuario = user.UserName;
                ViewBag.Contraseña = model.Password;
                return View();
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

En ese caso, el administrador al querer registrar un cliente, iria a una vista que tiene un formulario para registrarlo. Los ViewBag del controlador, son solo para en la vista hacer una comprobacion, si vienen como null, significa que esta creando y muestra el formulario, si no vienen como null es porque se acaba de registrar uno y muestra las credenciales de este para darselas al cliente. Pero si hago clic en el volver donde hay este codigo en la vista

```
<input class="btn btn-danger btn-block" value="Aceptar" type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("GestionarPublicaciones","Publicacion")'">
```

Me pide que me vuelva a loguear, o si hago ctrl+f5 tambien. Alguien sabe porq ue puede estar pasando esto? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Cambia esa linea por un `rememberBrowser:true`, y comentame si se arreglo tu problema.

```
 await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
```

Comment: No funciono Orlando, luego de crear un usuario y que me muestre sus credenciales, hago clic en el boton aceptar y tengo que volver a loguearme cuando se redirige al registro de usuarios.

Comment: Ya lo solucione, me di cuenta por la respuesta que me diste. Como estoy aprenidenod a usar Identity, tenia un concepto erroneo de lo que realizaba SignInManager, por lo que necesitaba era sacar completamente esa instruccion para que no se me loguee como el usuario que se acababa de registrar. Gracias.

Comment: Me alegra iMSn20 ;) suerte con tu proyecto.